# Azure B2C magic link email customization

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have added the magic link feature in my signin signup flow. I have changed the Restful provider to send email from custom email provider. How do I generate the magic link for **Confirm Account** to be passed in the template?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by template?

Are you using custom policies?

If, so refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint).

You have a choice of symmetric (secret key) or asymmetric (certificate).

There are two "[magic link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples)" samples plus a [sign-in](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link) one.